# I want to share my docker mongodb database with co-workers

Tags: database, windows, mongodb, docker, share

I am currently working on mongodb with docker on windows (windows containers).
I created my Database and I have been inserting info in it for about a month now .
But I have to share that specific database with my coworkers .
Unfortunately when exporting an image of my container it didn't have the database that I have been working on
I'm looking for a way to share my database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take container snapshots in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378777/how-to-take-container-snapshots-in-docker)